# Non-Linear Regression on model with time delay (dirac function)

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, nonlinear-regression

here is the equation:

$$y(t) = K_{2}\delta(t-\theta ) \Bigg(1-\frac{\tau_{1}e^{\frac{-(t-\theta)}{\tau_{1}}}-\tau_{2}e^{\frac{-(t-\theta)}{\tau_{2}}}}{\tau_{1}-\tau_{2}}\Bigg)$$

The parameters that need to be approximated are: $\tau_{1} $, $\tau_{2} $ and $\theta$ ($K_{2}$ is known).
The Issue as you can see is the dirac function, basically, the equation is only valid for $t>\theta$ (otherwise it's 0). How can I write a script that will do some regression to let me find the values of the parameters I need?

Edit: I can estimate $\theta$ so that leaves me with two parameters. So I can ignore $\theta$ for now and the problem effectively becomes: $$y(t) = K_{2} \Bigg(1-\frac{\tau_{1}e^{\frac{-(t)}{\tau_{1}}}-\tau_{2}e^{\frac{-(t)}{\tau_{2}}}}{\tau_{1}-\tau_{2}}\Bigg)$$
 I still don't think this model can be linearised.

Comment: Welcome to CV. I don't think this is an appropriate question for this site. You are asking someone to write the code which will linearize this function? Do you know any math software? If so, why not DIY and simulate this function?

Comment: @DJohnson Apologies, I wrongly worded my question, I just wished to know whether it is possible to do this or not, I'm not a statistician/mathematician by trade so I don't want to start working on something only to find out it was never possible to begin with. Would the Gauss-Newton method be appropriate for this task?

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful. I don't have an answer re G-N. We'll see how your question proceeds...